# not able to access helloworld

Tags: jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

```
I am using jboss eap 6.2 and deploying helloworld.war file on jboss in domain mode. I can access the admin console using http://XXX:9990/console
However http://XXX:9090/helloworld does not bring the default page. 
tried even with http://XXX:9090/helloworld/index.html
```

I verified that the application is deployed to the correct other-server-group and the server server-three is part of the group. Also the context /helloworld is correct.

```
Could some one suggest what might be the issue ? 
Accessing http://XXX:9090/ brings the welcome page of the server.
```

Comment: Did you change the port binding? The default is 8080 not 9090.

Comment: Yes I changed the port. If I deploy on main server group it works. Not able to access app when deployed on other server group.

Comment: You need to deploy to each server group you want the application on.